# SharedPreferences save-load does not work on Gingerbread. Ideas?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

So I have the implementation of a general SharedPreferences-class which serializes some text and saves it in a SharedPreferences String field. It works perfectly on my HTC One M8 device running Android 4.4.2. However, when I test it on my Samsung Galaxy S1 running rooted Gingerbread (2.2), it always returns "null" when reading the String. Any ideas what might be wrong?

If I try to load right after I've saved (in the same process), it returns the string. Only when I kill the process and relaunch, it is gone. Note: Relaunch from device. Not  recompile/redeploy. Weird.

Code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import com.myapp.Container.

/**
 */
public class SharedPrefsSavable {
    private final static String PrefsKey = "com.myapp";
    public static <T> T load(Class type, Context context) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PrefsKey, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        T userData = null;
        try {
            String key = getPreferencesId(type);
            String stringData = prefs.getString(key, null);
            if (stringData != null) {
                userData = (T) Container.Serializer.deserialize(type, stringData);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Container.Log.w("Unable to deserialize " + type + ": " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        if (userData == null) {
            try {
                userData = (T) type.newInstance();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }
        return userData;
    }

    public void save(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PrefsKey, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        String asString = Container.Serializer.serialize(this);
        String objectKey = getPreferencesId();
        editor.putString(objectKey, asString);
        editor.commit();
    }

    private static String getPreferencesId(Class<? extends SharedPrefsSavable> type) {
        return type.getName();
    }

    public String getPreferencesId() {
        return SharedPrefsSavable.getPreferencesId(this.getClass());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Red herring - it was a problem specific to my device, which had some corrupt state due to multiple reinstalls not going quite as they should. Leaving this answer here in case others come across the same problem.

Basically I monitored the file at

```
/dbdata/databases/com.myapp/shared_prefs/com.myapp_preferences.xml
```

I noticed that it never changed. I uninstalled the app and deleted `/dbdata/databases/com.myapp` entirely and then reinstalled. The files were recreated and this time it worked. So I'm guessing there were stale files/folders from a previous installation which my app now didn't have permission to alter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString( "Key", "value" );

        // retrive 

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( context);
        String value = prefs.getString("key","default" );
```

Comment: putInt takes second parameter int, not string. `public abstract SharedPreferences.Editor putInt (String key, int value)`

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't help.